# Regex - Match first two words but drop second word if it contains variables

Tags: regex

How do I match the first two words from the log description but I don't the second word if it contains a # and numbers.

Logs:

```
<14>Dec 19 08:48:44 Xwsdedserfse11 httpd: [century]: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 08:48:44 -0800|JohnnyDoe|auth|INFO|1|Successful login for 'JohnnyDoe' from 1.1.1.1 (authentication type: ldap) 
<12>Dec 19 08:25:18 Xwsdedserfse11 php: [century]: Tue, 19 Dec 2017 08:25:18 -0800||error|WARNING|1|Query #145050 used to generate source data is inactive.
```

My match should be 
Successful login 
Query
I have been working with different variation of this `(?:[^\|]*\|){5}(\S+\s)(\S+)\s` which pulls the first two words 
 and `(?:[^\|]*\|){5}(\S+\s)([a-zA_Z]+)\s\`
 and `(?:[^\|]*\|){5}(\S+\s)([^#0-9]+)\s` but this one doesn't pull Query from the second log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next regex: `(?:[^\|]*\|){5}(\S+)\s(?:[#\d]+|([a-zA-Z]+))\s`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<=[^\|]+?\|)([a-zA-Z]+?\s(?:[^#]+?\s)?)(?<=[^\|]*)
```